# Np skipping the draft release step

Tags: npm, np

np's totally skipping the draft release step, and I don't know how I made it do that.

At first, it skipped pushing the tags because it "didn't detect an upstream branch". This was weird to me because it had to push the changes somehow. Then I type `git push --set-upstream origin master`, and that handled the tag pushing. Now it pushes the tags... but it skips the release draft step. I'm not using any flags, just `np`.

I do not know how to reproduce this. I've tried multiple projects; I've tried uninstalling and then reinstalling np, and the draft release step just isn't executing.

I've looked at:

- [#431](https://github.com/sindresorhus/np/issues/431) (actually throws an error, mine has no error)
- [#382](https://github.com/sindresorhus/np/issues/382) (shows "command failed", mine shows nothing) and other branch pulls for ideas--no dice.

Here's what my terminal (GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)) looks like.

```sh
Publish a new version of testfordraftrelease (current: 1.0.1)

? No commits found since previous release, continue? (y/N) y
? No commits found since previous release, continue? Yes
? Select semver increment or specify new version (Use arrow keys)
? Select semver increment or specify new version patch  1.0.2

[02:51:34] Prerequisite check [started]
[02:51:34] Ping npm registry [started]
[02:51:36] Ping npm registry [completed]
[02:51:36] Check npm version [started]
[02:51:37] Check npm version [completed]
[02:51:37] Verify user is authenticated [started]
[02:51:41] Verify user is authenticated [completed]
[02:51:41] Check git version [started]
[02:51:41] Check git version [completed]
[02:51:41] Check git remote [started]
[02:51:43] Check git remote [completed]
[02:51:43] Validate version [started]
[02:51:43] Validate version [completed]
[02:51:43] Check for pre-release version [started]
[02:51:43] Check for pre-release version [completed]
[02:51:43] Check git tag existence [started]
[02:51:45] Check git tag existence [completed]
[02:51:45] Prerequisite check [completed]
[02:51:45] Git [started]
[02:51:45] Check current branch [started]
[02:51:45] Check current branch [completed]
[02:51:45] Check local working tree [started]
[02:51:45] Check local working tree [completed]
[02:51:45] Check remote history [started]
[02:51:45] Check remote history [completed]
[02:51:45] Git [completed]
[02:51:45] Cleanup [started]
[02:51:45] Cleanup [completed]
[02:51:45] Installing dependencies using npm [started]
[02:51:47] → npm WARN testfordraftrelease@1.0.1 No repository field.
[02:51:47] → up to date in 0.295s
[02:51:47] → found 0 vulnerabilities
[02:51:47] → [object Object]
[02:51:47] Installing dependencies using npm [completed]
[02:51:47] Running tests using npm [started]
[02:51:48] → > testfordraftrelease@1.0.1 test C:\Users\Choppy\Documents\Actual Documents\Coding\Actual Projects\Test
[02:51:48] → > echo 'Hi'
[02:51:48] → 'Hi'
[02:51:48] → [object Object]
[02:51:48] Running tests using npm [completed]
[02:51:48] Bumping version using npm [started]
[02:51:49] → v1.0.2
[02:51:49] → [object Object]
[02:51:49] Bumping version using npm [completed]
[02:51:49] Publishing package using npm [started]
[02:51:51] Publishing package using npm (waiting for input…) [title changed]
[02:51:51] → ? Enter OTP:
841029
? Enter OTP: 8
? Enter OTP: 84
? Enter OTP: 841
? Enter OTP: 8410
? Enter OTP: 84102
? Enter OTP: 841029
? Enter OTP: 841029
[02:51:55] → undefined
[02:51:55] Publishing package using npm [title changed]
[02:52:00] Publishing package using npm [completed]
[02:52:00] Pushing tags [started]
[02:52:04] Pushing tags [completed]

 testfordraftrelease 1.0.2 published
```

### Expected behavior

I expected the draft release step to occur whenever I use np and no errors occur.

### Environment

np - 5.0.3
Node.js - 10.16.0
npm - 6.10.2
Git - 2.16.2.windows.1
OS - Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

After searching the util.js, cli.js, ui.js, and index.js of the np package, I learned that it (the release portion, at least) doesn't detect the GitHub repo through the git folder. It detects it through the package.json.

This means that if you `npm init` a package before `git init`, it won't add the GitHub repo to the package.json file. If you forget or don't know to add it manually, np will skip the release draft phase.

This requires either an update to get the repo info from git/the git directory, or an echo/console.log to have the user update their package.json file.

**package.json where np *did not* draft a release:**

```
{
  "name": "testfordraftrelease",
  "version": "1.0.11",
  "description": "Using this to test np",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo 'Hi'"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**package.json where np *did* draft a release:**

```
{
  "name": "testfordraftrelease",
  "version": "1.0.11",
  "description": "Using this to test np",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo 'Hi'"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Crowbrammer/TestRepoForNP.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Crowbrammer/TestRepoForNP/issues"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```